# Using MaterialEntryRenderer Placeholdercolor and Cursorcolor not Changed in Xamarin forms Ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

How to change the placeholder color and cursor color in ios renderer? I have changed the TintColor property in Placeholder and Cursor color in Control.AttributedPlaceholder, it is not changed the placeholder color and cursor color in ios

public class CustomMaterialEntryRenderer : MaterialEntryRenderer
{

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we don't need to use `MaterialEntryRenderer`  .

Just set `PlaceholderColor` in Forms project , it will change Placeholder and cursor color .

```
<Entry Placeholder="test" Visual="Material" Focused="Entry_Focused" Unfocused="Entry_Unfocused"/>

private void Entry_Focused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
{
   var entry = sender as Entry;
   entry.PlaceholderColor = Color.Red;
}

private void Entry_Unfocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
{
   var entry = sender as Entry;
   entry.PlaceholderColor = Color.Gray;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it has been acheived in MaterialEntry also like Entry entry = ((Entry)sender) as Entry;
            entry.PlaceholderColor = Color.Gray;

Comment: Yes, i have another problem in ios once compressed sounds like robotic in webview created in below path
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68284286/how-to-avoid-robotic-sound-when-playing-video-in-ios-xamarin-forms